# DPDT Relay H-Bridge

Tags: relay, h-bridge, dpdt

I am trying to make a circuit so I can use an Arduino to change the rotation of a DC motor, so I am thinking about using an H-bridge made of a DPDT relay connected to the arduino. Would it work? Also can you draw me a diagram of how a DPDT relay H bridge would look like?

Comment: I’d replace the relays with mosfets.

Comment: You have two basic kinds of DPDT relays: "make before break" and "break before make." You'll need to first decide which of these you prefer. The 1st will short out your power supply, but that may be acceptable. The 2nd will let the motor free-spin a bit, but that may also be acceptable. You could also consider the case where you short out the motor contacts for a moment (but without shorting the power supply), as this case will cause the motor to "self-brake." That may also be desired. If so, again you need to let us understand what you expect during the transition.

Comment: Hi, I see that you are a new user. In general we don't just do your design work for you. We help when there is an indication that you have done enough work by yourself to start with. You can just google how a DPDT H-Bridge would look like, and post how you think it should be with a schematic. Then we can suggest improvements or alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

This will reverse the direction of the motor. The separate switch MOSFET is used to turn the motor on and off, or control the speed via PWM.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGzbUn.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If the motor is reversed while it is still spinning it will be braked by D1 even if the MOSFET is off (and you would probably want to ensure that it is off until the motor is stopped).

Comment: With PWM operation, wouldn't D1 also brake the motor when the amplitude is just at zero?

Comment: @ClaudioCardoso Amplitude = 0 is the same as MOSFET off.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have the time to draw the circuit, but by googling you will finds lots and some may even have code. I would use a BTS7960 bridge. They can be gotten for less than $10.00 US. It comes complete with heatsink. You will need at least 8V (powers bridge and motor) to make it work. Please note: the ground of the power is connected to the ground of the logic on the bridge. You will also have to connect your VCC from the Arduino, this powers the logic circuits on the bridge but not the motor. This will drive a 20A or less motor without problems. You can PWM it, change directions, dynamic break with strictly software control. You need to use one of the PWM outputs (UNO the digital I/O pins 3, 5, 6, 9, 10 and 11) on the Arduino, and it will work with the default PWM frequency.  On these pins the analogWrite function is used to set the duty cycle of a PWM which if I remember correctly is about 490 Hz on pins 5 and 6 with the others being 980 Hz.